# Trignometry question find the given

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\cos A=3/4$ then what is the value of $32\sin(A/2)\sin(5A/2)$?

Comment: If $\cos(A)=\frac{3}{4}$, then you should know one of two possible values for $A$ in the range $[0,2\pi)$ (*hint: use inverse trig functions*).  Figuring out those possible values should be your first step.  Once you know those values, then it is just a matter of plugging them into your second expression and evaluating.

Comment: Yes, I can.  I will not however until you show a bit of effort and it becomes clear what you are actually having difficulty with.  Again, break it down into smaller steps.  If $\cos(A)=\frac{3}{4}$, then what is $A$?

Comment: Yaa i tried a lot it is 3,4,17^1/2 but i cant find the angle

Comment: Have you never heard of an [inverse trigonometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)?  Have you never heard of $\arccos$?  (*sometimes written in certain parts of the world as $\cos^{-1}$ but not to be confused with $\frac{1}{\cos}$*)

Comment: Look - we're not going to solve it just because you ask us to. Edit your original post to demonstrate what you've tried and what steps you're stuck on.

Comment: I find that incredibly hard to believe.  Inverse trig functions are taught the same week or the week after trig functions.  If $\cos(x)=y$ (*and $x$ is between $0$ and $\pi$ if referring to angles in radians, otherwise between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$ if referring to degrees*) then $x=\arccos(y)$.  That is all you need to know for inverse trig functions for now.  Now, continue.

Comment: @JMoravitz No, the information about the quadrant $A$ lives in is irrelevant.

Comment: @egreg in some problems it will be.  It happens to work out nicely for this problem, but that is no reason to gloss over the potential issue that it may cause in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely know that $\sin\alpha\sin\beta=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(\alpha-\beta)-\cos(\alpha+\beta))$. With $\alpha=5A/2$ and $\beta=A/2$, you get
$$
32\sin\frac{5A}{2}\sin\frac{A}{2}=
16(\cos2A-\cos3A)
$$
Now apply other known formulas: both $\cos2A$ and $\cos3A$ can be expressed in terms of $\cos A$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html